# Wrong UNIX Timestamp From the Meetup API

Tags: php, json, api, meetup

I'm having a problem with the Meetup API and wondering if anyone has experienced something similar, or would know how to deal with the issue.

There seems to be a problem with the timestamp coming back from my API call. The timestamp I'm getting back is 1320112800000, which converts to Sep. 17th, '02 - 12:00 AM (M. jS, 'y - g:i A). Is there something really obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to post what result you were expecting?

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp is likely correct.  1320112800000ms is 1320112800 seconds.  Using [unixtimestamp.com](http://unixtimestamp.com) to convert this, it comes to 10/31/11 @9:00:00pm EST.

Comment: +1 for inclusion of the timezone, as that may also be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Javascript timestamp, which is a standard unix timestamp, but in milliseconds. If you lop off 3 zeroes, you'll get

```
 1320112800 -> Oct 31/2011 20:00:00
```